# How to find page load time in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Is this the right way to find page load time in angular2+??
I don't think so, It's just the time difference between the route change.How can we add the page DOM content load time to it.??

```
this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    const navigationComplete = val instanceof NavigationEnd;
    const navigationStart = val instanceof NavigationStart;
    if(navigationStart){
        this.navigationStartTime = (new Date).getTime();
    }
    if (navigationComplete) {
        this.currentPage = this.router.url; // Current page route
        this.currentLocation = (this.platformLocation as any).location.href; // Current page url
        let endTime = (new Date).getTime();
        this.pageLoadTime = Number(endTime) - Number(this.navigationStartTime); // Page load time
    }
});
```

Comment: use [chrome dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/) to analyse performance, it will also so real load time of the page.

Comment: You can use ngOnInit and which is a life cycle hook called by Angular2 to indicate that Angular is done creating the component.

Comment: Thank u, but it will works only for components,right ?? My code is present inside a provider.I'am writing this as a common provider,which can find page load time for all the pages present in the application.Inside a provider how can I detect the view is completely loaded ??

Comment: @ShanilSasikumar Have you found any generic way of finding actual page load time after all the API done & page fully rendered. I'm also looking for it.

Answer (score 2):

you can definitely use chrome dev tools to analyse perfomance as mentioned by @AurA

separately in the above all scripts you can initialise

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timerStart = Date.now();
</script>
```

and in the main component

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   console.log("Time until reaching run phase: ", Date.now() - $window.timerStart);
}
```

Havent tested. But should run.

Comment: Thank u, but it will works only for components,right ?? My code is present inside a provider.I'am writing this as a common provider,which can find page load time for all the pages present in the application.Inside a provider how can I detect the view is completely loaded ??

Comment: you can call the provider function in each component ngAfterViewInit(), to make it generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NavigationStart` and `ngAfterViewInit` to track exact load time.

Comment: Thank u, but it will works only for components,right ?? My code is present inside a provider.I'am writing this as a common provider,which can find page load time for all the pages present in the application.Inside a provider how can I detect the view is completely loaded ??

Comment: Yes, It will work with components only because these functions are component's lifecycle so they can be detected by component only. If you want to put it in common/provider, you have to make a function in your provider and have to call it on each component's `ngAfterViewInit `