# Angular 7 how to calculate the time a component take to completely load on the DOM

Tags: angular, performance, angular7

I am trying to get the time a component take to totally load into the dom, using the following inside `ngOninit()` from [this answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49934797/how-to-find-page-load-time-in-angular?answertab=active#tab-top):

```
ngOnInit()
{
    var time = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart
    console.log(time)
}
```

The result was like:

> -1544706869570

I used `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    var time = window.performance.timing.domContentLoadedEventEnd-window.performance.timing.navigationStart
    console.log(time)
  }
```

And it was the same result.

How to transform it into seconds, and is there a better solution to heck the component load in angular 7 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure it with window.performance.now in milliseconds like this:

```
startTime! : number
initTime! : number
contentInitTime! : number
viewInitTime! : number

printTime(time : number) {
  console.log(`Global loading ${ time }ms`)
  console.log(`Global loading ${ time / 1000 }s`)
  console.log(`Component loading ${ time - this.startTime }ms`)
  console.log(`Component loading ${ (time - this.startTime) / 1000 }s`)
}
// Created
constructor() {
  this.startTime = window.performance.now()
  this.printTime(this.startTime)
}
// Initialized by angular
ngOnInit() {
  this.initTime = window.performance.now()
  this.printTime(this.initTime)
}
// Rendered without children
ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.contentInitTime = window.performance.now()
  this.printTime(this.contentInitTime)
}
// Rendered with children
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.viewInitTime = window.performance.now()
  this.printTime(this.viewInitTime)
}
```

Comment: @alim1990 updated my answer with an output in seconds